# Laravel migration cancelled

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

when I trying to migrate something I get this error:

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command?
Command Cancelled!
```

Im running a centOS 6.5 server without Plesk 12
Is there anyway to figure out what the error is or how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you please take your time to read this (guide)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] and provide as much relevant information you can. That way it's easier for people to help you :)

Comment: this means that the application is in production environment did you set `debug` to `true` in `app/config/app.php` ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Simple,

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
   return 'development';
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: tnx! helped me a lot! :D

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer considering it doesn't explain what it does and that the change could be dangerous. This forces a dev environment disabling entirely the laravel migration protection for a production environment.
Just use `php artisan migrate --force` when you are sure that you can migrate safely on a production environment or use another `APP_ENV` setting if you are not in production.

Answer (score 10):

A bit late for answer but just for info purpose you can use `php artisan migrate --force` to avoid it OR in laravel 5.2 they are using a key `env` in config/app.php configure it to avoid this prompt
reference https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php

Answer (score 9):

Just use --force flag in production:

```
php artisan migrate --force
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#running-migrations

> Forcing Migrations To Run In Production
>
> Some migration operations are destructive, which means they may cause
>   you to lose data. In order to protect you from running these commands
>   against your production database, you will be prompted for
>   confirmation before the commands are executed. To force the commands
>   to run without a prompt, use the --force flag.

Answer (score 1):

Change your environment first from production to local . /bootstrap/start.php somewhere line no 26

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    // find your machine name and replace mine 
    'local' => array('hassanjamal.local'),
));
```

Comment: It was this:
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
 'local' => array('homestead'),
));

Comment: Where should I change it to?

Comment: change homestead to your machine name

Comment: its a vps, should not matter what my machine name is right?

Answer (score 1):

I've just bumped into this problem as well. If you don't want to reconfigure your app (which is probably a good idea) hit 'Y' and then enter instead of just enter. It will go on even in production setting.